# in C is a lookup table a replacement for variable variables like in bash||php

Tags: c

In Bash I would use `variable variables` to store the name of a `variable` or `pointer` so I could use it in a different function. Is a `lookup table` the correct replacement in C?

My problem is I have created two variables/objects in

**source_A.**

```
frameRate_1 = gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw",
               "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 25, 1,  
          NULL);
frameRate_2 = gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw",
               "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 60, 1,  
          NULL);
```

In Source B, I read parameters from `fileOne.cfg` that has the name of the variable\object to load for the correct parameters, this is the `name` of the variable\object to use from `source_A`.

**fileOne.cfg**

```
frameRate_2
```

**source_B**

```
//....Load parameter into variable  
// useThisFrameRate=frameRate_2
applyFrameRate(&useThisFrameRate);
```

This name is then passed to a function in source_C that will use the `name` to reference the variable/object from `source_A`.

**source_C**

```
applyFrameRate (char *useThisFramerate){
g_object_set( G_OBJECT ( name ),  "caps",  *useThisFramerate, NULL );
}
```

Reading the MAN pages and some explanations I can see how lookup tables can be used to store and reference static and dynamic variables, but I could not see how to reference a variable name using the lookup tables and pass this as a reference.

Or am I over thinking this and should I be using `&` somehow to get to the `name` object by reference?

Comment: Use pointers and hence `&`. I've not read it all, but from your opening para and closing para, that's probably what you need.

Answer (score 1):

> I could not see how to reference a variable name using the lookup tables and pass this as a reference

That is because C does not provide such mechanism. In fact, once the compiler is done with your code, variable names do not exist, except in debug symbol files, which are not part of your program anyway.

To use look-up tables with names, you need to maintain name lists yourself. For example, you could make a parallel array of names to look up configuration values, and use its index to reference an array of frame rates:

```
const char *frConfig[] = {"frameRate_1", "frameRate_2", "frameRate_3"};
GstCaps *frLookup[] = {frameRate_1, frameRate_2, frameRate_3};
```

Now you can do look-up like this:

```
GstCaps *lookupByName(const char *name) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i != sizeof(frConfig)/sizeof(frConfig[0]) ; i++) {
        if (strcmp(frConfig[i], name) == 0) {
            return frLookup[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL; // Not found
}
```